# Is nonatomic worth it?

Tags: cocoa-touch, performance

I've seen many times @property defined as nonatomic for performance reasons. Is there any evidence that this is worth it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a property is not declared as `nonatomic`, the synthesized accessor will use locks to ensure that the property is thread-safe. When a lock is unnecessarily used, it adds unneeded messages to your program. The locking operation itself should also be atomic, which means that the processor will lock the memory bus. This can slow down your program as well as others. If a property is not frequently accessed, you probably won't notice a difference, but you definitely want to use it if the property will be used frequently. Overall, though, why not use it? It is a few extra characters which could potentially cause your program to speed up.

Comment: My concern is actually if the risk of running into some deadlock/race condition/whatever is worth this extra bump in performance.

Comment: You should never use `nonatomic` on something that could be used in multiple threads. I guess I assumed that was obvious, since atomicity is essential when something could be accessed by multiple threads, and you were asking if it was beneficial to use it on single threaded applications.

Comment: The question was "is it worth it?" - and that question can't be answered without measuring particular code.

Comment: @James Which is why I didn't say yes or no. I described reasons that it *could* provide benefits, and pointed out that there is no reason not to use it when you can. It's not like it requires refactoring the entire program. I could have answered similarly to a question like "Is it worth it to not place `sleep(1)` after every statement?".

Comment: @ughoavgfhw, I should have put my position more strongly.  Adding nonatomic is wrong, unless and until you measure its actual impact on your own code.  nonatomic is additional code that should only be added when necessary.  To put it another way, premature optimization is wrong - and that's exactly what adding nonatomic is.

Comment: @James Except that atomic accessors actually use more code. You might have to write less, but the executed code is more. And there is nothing wrong with premature optimization, it is just a waste of time. In this case, that time is tiny, so measuring to see if you need it is worse than just using it. But of course you are entitled to your opinion, so I guess we'll just have to disagree on this.